# How do you manage multiple external libraries in an Android project?(Eclipse,Git,ADT)

Tags: java, android, android-library

The problem basically is if you have multiple developers working on a project and the project references multiple external libraries then it becomes hard to keep track of library versions and face issues related to it and the setup time increases every-time you import the project on a new machine.
Technologies used(eclipse,ADT,GIT)

Comment: keep u r code on git and use VSS tool for libray.... so everybody can refer same lib version from vss .........

Answer (score 0):

Tried a bunch of options-build mgmt tools,repo managers and the likes.
Heres whats worked for me.
This solution is targeted for ppl who are not familiar with build management systems.
High level:
Store all the libraries in a separate GIT repo that's centrally hosted(say:bitbucket).
In your android project add the above repo as a sub-module.

Now to get your project working you just have to import all the projects in your submodule in eclipse and in the project properties under Android point the project to these libraries.

You are good to go!

Great article on GIT(jump to the submodules  section if you are familiar with git)
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html

Tips:
1)Add the git module with the -b option so that you can track changes from the master repo of the submodule(refer above tutorial)
2)While importing the libraries, import them as a general project(vs android proj)...for some reason eclipse was not letting me import the projects via the android project wizard.
3)Understand the nuances of how Submodules work.

I`ll have to probably move to a sophisticated build management system sooner or later where  this is handled in a different way but this works for now.
I tried to reference the libraries via Gradles dependency management process but getting the whole thing to work just takes soo much time for a noob.
Feel free to post questions if something was not clear.
Hope this saves people time.

Answer (score 0):

you may need [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) ,based on a new building system gradle.

when you need import a library,you just need to put a single line in build.gradle if this library is in Maven Central Repository.Android Studio will automatically download library, then you can use it in you code.You don't have to care too much about managing multiple libraries

if you're developing individually,switching to Android Studio is a better choice.